# How to set Map location from any city or place name

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

This is the way where I am taking the current location

```
    NSString* lat = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
NSString* lon = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

    NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@,%@&output=csv&sensor=false",lat,lon];
    NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:rq delegate:self];
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

and in the connection delegate method I am getting the current location name.**200,9,"IITI Computer Education, Wadala, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400067, India"**  in the simulator.

Now my question is How can we set annotation on the same place in the map using the string place name which I got previously.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make an objective c class make your .h file look like following

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <Mapkit/MKAnnotation.h>
 @interface annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

 {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
  NSString *title;
  NSString *subtitle;

 }

   @property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
   @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
   @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

  @end
```

Now in .m file

```
#import "annotation.h"

@implementation annotation

@synthesize  coordinate,title,subtitle;

@end
```

Now in your controller.m file where you want to add an annotaion make an import of above file

```
#import "annotation.h"
```

now you can use the following function to add anotation to any cordinate

```
-(void)addAnnotations{

annotation *userPositionAnnote = [[annotation alloc]init];
userPositionAnnote.title = @"My Current Position";
userPositionAnnote.coordinate = SetYourCordinates; // set your cordinates here where you want to add annotaion

[YourMap addAnnotation:userPositionAnnote];

MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
region.center = userPositionAnnote.coordinate;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.001;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001;

[YourMap setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

hope this will help you