# Search for a location in a map view on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, uisearchbar

I have a MapView and a SearchBar. I enter some place name into the search bar. I need the MapView to search for the place I entered and mark that place with an annotation. Can anyone suggest the best steps to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google api  and NSXMLParser to get the coordinates of the searched place and then add annotation at that particular coordinate

For NSXMLParser look at my answer in   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845732/xml-parser-objective-c/10845892#10845892

You can use the following google api for getting the latlng

```
NSMutableString *url    =   [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="];

// replace searchAddressString with your address from search bar.

[url appendString:[searchAddressString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@","]];
[url appendString:@"&sensor=true"];
```

Now to add annotation you can follow my answer here  [How to set Map location from any city or place name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682102/how-to-set-map-location-from-any-city-or-place-name/11682659#11682659)

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Is there Need To Include Google API .. and need to Write code for NSXMLParser

Comment: @Vanitha No it is not necessary to do so, if you can get the coordinates of the address by using any other method or another api its fine.

Comment: K Thank You.. Let me Try and tell U!! Please be available

Comment: Where to include the Above Code?

Comment: Sorry Im new To iPhone.. I need some Guidence to complete the Task

Comment: @Vanitha you are using a UISearchbar and hope using its delegate - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar you can set the NSXMLParser to use google api or whatever you think easy for you when you get you coordinates save them in CLLocationCoordinate2D and call the addAnnotations function which in my answer the second link of How to set Map location one

Comment: @Vanitha if its still hard for you to get it i can setup an example for you if you want give me your Email id.

Comment: s...  vanitharaja90@gmail.com

Comment: @Vanitha yup i'll send you but it will take time cause i am also doing something of my own :) you will get it within an hour

Answer (score 0):

Search the address like this:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)addressLocation:(NSString*)name 
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                           [name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        // error
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    return location;
}
```

than create an annotation (`NSObject <MKAnnotation>`) with the returned location object and add it to your mapview:

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: When this Method will get called

Comment: Your viewcontroller needs to implement UISearchBarDelegate, set the Seach bar's delegate as your VC, then implement the method searchBarSearchButtonClicked:, that will call [self addressLocation:searchBar.text];

Comment: Is there No Need For NSXMLParser ?

Comment: Nope, in this way you make a request for a CSV response, that you can easily parse with componentsSeparatedByString:@","

Comment: Thanks for your Easiest Approach... Great Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchbar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    NSString *searchURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=13.0604220,80.2495830&radius=500&types=restaurant&name=%@&sensor=false&key=%@",searchBar.text,kGooglePlaceAPIkey];
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:searchURL];
    NSURLRequest *URLReq=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:URLReq delegate:self];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [NSURLConnection  sendAsynchronousRequest:URLReq   queue:queue     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data,NSError *error) 
     {

         xmlParser=[[XMLParser alloc]loadXMLByURL:searchURL];
         [self.tableView reloadData];
         [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
         DisplayMap *selected = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
         for(int i=0;i<[xmlParser.places count];i++) {

             currentPlace=[[xmlParser places]objectAtIndex:i];
             MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
             region.center.latitude = [currentPlace.latitude doubleValue];
             region.center.longitude = [currentPlace.longitude doubleValue];
             region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.03f;
             region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.03f;
             [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
             [mapView setDelegate:self];
             mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
             mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
             DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
             ann.item=i;
             ann.title = currentPlace.name;
             ann.subtitle = currentPlace.address; 
             ann.coordinate = region.center; 
             [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
             if (currentSelectPlace == i)
                 selected = ann;
         }

         if(value == 1) {

             if(currentSelectPlace+1) {

                 [mapView setCenterCoordinate:selected.coordinate animated:YES];
                 [mapView selectAnnotation:selected animated:NO];
             }

         }
         [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

     }];
    [self.mapView reloadInputViews];

}


- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchbar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```